# How to appear/fill a div from bottom to up to get following effect using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to get the following effect, that the image should appear/revel/fill from bottom to top. So far what I tried (check my code) and it fills from top to bottom, which is the opposite I want. Is there any suggestion or solution to this problem. Is it possible to reserve the animation I already did?

[image]

```css
.photo-container{
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;

}
 img{
   height: 400px;
   width: 300px;
   object-fit: cover;
 }

.fill-image {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: fillBottomToTop;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
   
  }
  

    
@keyframes fillBottomToTop {
    from {
      height: 0;
    }
    to {
      height: 400px;
    }
}
```

```css
.photo-container{
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

img{
 height: 400px;
 width: 300px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.fill-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fillBottomToTop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
    
@keyframes fillBottomToTop {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container">
  <div class="fill-image">
    <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with background-image and one element:

```css
.photo-container{
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:
    url(https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg)
    center/cover padding-box content-box;
  padding-top:400px;
  animation: fillBottomToTop 2s 2s forwards;
}
    
@keyframes fillBottomToTop {
  to {
    padding-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use an overlay to cover the image and have it reveal the picture underneath? Like this:

```css
.photo-container{
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

img{
 height: 400px;
 width: 300px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  animation-name: fillBottomToTop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background: #fff;
}
  

    
@keyframes fillBottomToTop {
  from {
    height: 400px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container">
  <div class="fill-image">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" >
  </div>
</div>
```